# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in a webview

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

I have an app that uses android webview and of recent I have been getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. The problem with the stacktrace is that it does not point to any of my java class, so it kind of hard to fix this bug. The stacktrace is below:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$1.handleMessage (WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:153)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)

at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1496)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1386)

I have searched google but dont seem to find an answer.
```

Comment: Show the detail code about it .

Comment: hello keliuyue, i do not have an idea where this error is thrown cos i have a lot of classes in my app

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is about the activity thread. When u call the webview, maybe it is in use by other thread. Try to setEmpty, before put data in the webview again.